# Access denied when issuing net session on a Win 7 32bit workstation

Tags: windows-7

Although I am a domain admin, I get this message when issuing this command on Windows 7

```
C:\>net session
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Comment: It's probably UAC getting in your way. If I had a penny for every "access denied on Vista/Win7" question that turned out to be simply UAC, I'd be a rich man by now. :(

Answer (score 2):

### This is anecdotal and your mileage may vary.

On my win7 box I get your error when there are no connections to my Win7 box. If I map a drive from another PC (example: WinXP) back to the Win7 box and then run "net session" on the Win7 box, I'll get results

> =Computer               =Username            =Client Type      = Opens Idle time
>
> =\192.168.150.150      =ADMINISTRATOR        =Windows 2002 S...     =2 00:00:00
>
> =The command completed successfully.

Hope that helps (sorry for the poor editing-its not courier)

Answer (score 2):

Right Click and "Run As Administrator"

Comment: when you run commands such as 'net use' the results are not the same as the original user.